# How to safely wrap an object into an array in TypeScript?

Tags: django, angular, typescript

I am trying to submit an angular form to a backend API implemented in Django. when I submit the form it shows the following error "string indices must be integers"

**Post Request method**

```
postEntries(formData: MeasurementChange): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + this.postDataUrl, formData);
        }
```

**Post request sends in the following format**

```
{id: 2, percent_complete: 45}
id: 2
percent_complete: 45
```

**API accepts the following format**

```
[{
   "id":1,
   "percent_complete": 33
}]
```

How can I wrap my object in API accepted format/Array?

Comment: Probably `return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + this.postDataUrl, [formData]);`

Comment: that worked pretty smooth, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create an array and use push method to add the object,

**`myArray : any = [];`**

and then,

**`this.myArray.push(yourObj);`**

Answer (score 0):

Simply use square brackets:

```
myObj = {id: 2, percent_complete: 45}
wrapped = [myObj]
```